# How do I see the logs of a VSCode Language Server process?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

### Situation

I'm experimenting with writing a [VSCode Language Server Protocol (LSP) Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide#implementing-a-language-server). I've got it running as follows:

- An `lsp-server` process which is launched by running `haskell-lsp-example-exe` from terminal
- An `lsp-client` written in Typescript which, for now, basically just launches `lsp-server` (it's based on the [lsp-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-sample) repo)

The `lsp-server` is launch as follows:

```
# extension.ts
let serverOptions: ServerOptions = {
  run: {
    command: "haskell-lsp-example-exe"
  },
}
```

The `lsp-client` is launched using `code --extensionDevelopmentPath="path/to/extension"`

I can see that it launches correctly, and I can find its `pid` through Activity Monitor (I'm on Mac).

### Question

How can I see the logs of this process which is spawned by VSCode?

### Context

I have tried the following:

- In `lsp-client/package.json` I set the following which gives me the messages going back and forth. But not the logs of `lsp-server`.:

```
    "languageServerExample.trace.server": {
      "scope": "window",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "off",
        "messages",
        "verbose"
      ],
      "default": "verbose",
      "description": "Traces the communication between VS Code and the language server."
    }
```

- I've also tried opening up dev tools in the launched instance of VSCode, but that gives the logs of `lsp-client`
- The log labelled `Log (Extension Host)` in the launched instance of VSCode also doesn't look too useful

Thanks in advance for any help!